# How to ensure page loaded before calling javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas element in my page. I need that to finish loading before calling javascript file .any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery and put your code inside a function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // put code here
});
```

Comment: I want to call another .js file . Is it possible to do within this function

Comment: I'm not sure whether by "call another" you mean load an additional JavaScript file or call a JavaScript function. But either should be possible within the $(document).ready().

Comment: If you've referenced another javascript file, you can be sure that it's loaded by the time this function executes.  You can call any function from your page at that point.

Comment: @JohnMunsch: I mean call another javascript file. I dont know how to call the file from within ready(). I read that load does not work. Can you pls give example

Answer (score 2):

Put the `<script>` tag somewhere after the `<canvas>` tag.

Or use jQuery (ugh) and its `document ready` thing, whatever...

Answer (score 1):

The old and best way is to place JS code towards the end of the page, just inside the closing body tag. Thus you can assure that the DOM is ready.